# Прозрачный фон у WebView

Tags: java, javafx, webview, opacity, прозрачность

Нужно сделать прозрачный фон у WebView в JavaFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final com.sun.webkit.WebPage webPage = 
com.sun.javafx.webkit.Accessor.getPageFor(engine);
webPage.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Comment: Это не то, что мне нужно. Мне нужен прозрачные фон у компонента WebView на непрозрачной сцене. Мне нужно, чтобы WebView был прозрачным, чтобы его цвет задавался из HTML, который там находится.

Comment: Тогда так будет

Comment: Ну так что получилось?

Comment: Спасибо, это работает. Но есть проблема Eclipse показывает предупреждение: Access restriction: The type 'WebPage' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar')

Comment: Создай новый вопрос

Comment: По правилам stackOverflow два вопроса в тему не вмещают

Comment: Создате и я с удовольстием попытаюсь ответить